# Java Program output printed in random position in Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, logging, slf4j, stderr

I have a JUnit class in Eclipse project. It is like the following:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
/*some other imports*/

public class _JunitTests{
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(_JunitTests.class);   
    public void test(int num){
            logger.info("**** tests no."+num+" ***");
            /* some code */
    }   
    @Test
    public static void test1() {
            test(1);
    } 
    @Test
    public static void test2() {
            test(2);
    } 
    @Test
    public static void test3() {
            test(3);
    } 
    @Test
    public static void test1() {
            test(1);
    } 
}
```

When I run all the tests, I was expecting output such as[class information of info is ignored]

```
**** tests no.1 ***
/* somethings */

**** tests no.2 ***
/* somethings */

**** tests no.3 ***
/* somethings */
```

However, the result shown in console is usually messed up like:

```
**** tests no.1 ***
**** tests no.2 ***
**** tests 
/* somethings */

no.3 ***
/* somethings */
/* somethings */
```

This happens a lot before with my other codes when there are Exception messages.

My guess before is stderr and stdout are handled in different threads, and so the result would be displayed without a certain order.

Since the info from Logger is also red in Eclipse console, my guess is that it uses stderr to display the message? is it the case? if so, is there a way to solve the problem of messed up order? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which logging framework do you use with SLF4J? It could be that the logging framework is configured to write the log messages asynchronously in a background thread.

You can try to replace the log call with a `System.out.println()` and see if that produces the output you expect. If it does you may want to reconfigure the logging framework to log the messages synchronously.

Comment: Oh, the other output messages are just produced by `System.out.println()`. Can I configure SLF4J to synch with stdout?

Comment: SLF4J is a facade API that serves as a uniform logging API for a large number of logging frameworks. The configuration should be made in the logging framework that you are using. This could be e.g. logback or log4j. How to make the configuration depends on which logging framework you use in your system.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Just found out mine is `Simple` binding, by default it [`outputs to stderr`](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html).